# Storing Today's Date in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, date

When my html form is submitted, I want today's date also stored in one column along with the data given by the form in mysql table.

My php code:

```
#some code
$date = date('d-m-Y');
#some code
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1(rollNo, password, name, item, place, description, contact, date) VALUES('$rollNo', '$password', '$name', '$item', '$place', '$description', '$contact', '$date') ";
```

But for some reason, every time form is submitted, in the date column '0000-00-00' is stored instead of today's date. I tried using different formats(d/m/Y etc.), but didn't work. I have checked that in MySQL table, date column's type is date, not string. I am a newbie in php and MySQL and I don't know why this is happening.

Also, I want this page to daily(at 11:59 PM) send mail of that day's entries. For that, I am planning to check every entry's date with today's date, and send mail of only those that match. Please tell me if there is another simpler method of doing it.

EDIT:
Just to make it clear,  date column's type is `DATE`.

Comment: You can use the built-in function [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) instead.

Comment: In regards to your (actual) problem, check what your column is set to. Google it also, you will find many results that relate to yours, which will potentially lead you right back here on SO.

Comment: Plus, try changing this `$date = date('d-m-Y');` to `$date = date("d-m-Y");` most probably the cause, as it's not being treated as a string, which I think your column is probably set to VARCHAR or TEXT. Will need to know what your database schema is, in order to give you a definite answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, column's type is set to date. But NOW() with datetime works. Thanks!

Comment: It's always best to capitalize and `highlight` field types in questions. I.e.: `DATE` `DATETIME` `VARCHAR` etc. that way it's a lot clearer to read, and the way it's in there now, was not evident. Just glad your problem was solved, cheers.

Comment: Oh, Will keep that in mind.Thanks for the advice. Also, about last paragraph in my question, is there any function in php that grabs only the data entered last 24 hours? So that I don't have to compare dates for EVERY record and my page could work faster.

Comment: You're welcome and I made an actual highlight to `DATE` in your question. As for what you're asking, you could either use [`last_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) which could prove useful, or setup a `WHERE date <= 2013:21:12` type of thing. Or, ask another question (or Google) which are two viable options.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. last_insert_id() gives only last value of id, not all the values of id entered today.How do I use it for today?   And Setting up WHERE date = date(Y-m-d) is how you compare the entry date with today's date.

Comment: You're entirely right, my bad. You're best to do up another question. This thread stands at being flagged for being too chatty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
`dateandtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And using a simple substring, you can pick out the date (YYYY-MM-DD) with ease.

```
substr($sql['dateandtime'], 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use NOW() function of MySQL with column type DATETIME

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

You can also get just the date:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp

```
UPDATE table SET date = CURDATE();
```

Comment: using NOW() with type DATETIME, data doesn't get stored at all. It doesn't show any error message, goes to the next page like it is supposed to, but data doesn't get entried.

Comment: Then show us what your database schema is, as I stated in my comments under your original question, which I tend to think you haven't read... or have you? @DarshilChauhan – Comments can be just as good/useful as (given) answers. ;-)

Comment: @KohjahBreese : Sorry, Now it works. Was making a small mistake. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : I did read your comment. Thanks for the tip ! :-)

Comment: @KohjahBreese : NOW() works great with datetime. But CURDATE() shows syntax error. Also I didn't get the last line of your answer.

Comment: Does It work if you insert the date into VARCHAR?

Also, what is the output of SELECT CURDATE():

Comment: using this :dateandtime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE()    gives error in Sql syntax.